# Java parentheses index matching

Tags: java, string-matching, parentheses

I'm writing code to discover the **inner left most index** of a string (I'm doing string parsing)

Does the following code look correct?

```
 String   t = "VREF_DAC_BAND_GAP_(VALUE|DELTA|TRIM|K(7-0|15-9))"
 int lb_ind = t.indexOf('(', 0);      // left bracket index
 int rb_ind = t.indexOf(')', lb_ind); //right bracket index


 while((t.indexOf("(", lb_ind+1) != -1) && (t.indexOf("(", lb_ind+1) < rb_ind))
      {
          lb_ind = t.indexOf('(', lb_ind+1);
      }



 //  lb_ind should now contain the position of the inner left most parenthesis
```

Comment: What if the the input is `"a(b(c)) d(e(f))"`?

Comment: It returns "(" before the "c"

Comment: No, I mean what _should_ it be?

Comment: I'm not looking to handle strings of this case. i.e only one nested loop is allowed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, But you can use the below instead of while loop.

lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex) 
          Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified substring, searching backward starting at the specified index.

```
String   t = "VREF_DAC_BAND_GAP_(VALUE|DELTA|TRIM|K(7-0|15-9))"
int lb_ind = t.indexOf('(', 0);      // left bracket index
int rb_ind = t.indexOf(')', lb_ind); //right bracket index

if(t.lastIndexOf("(", rb_ind) != -1)
  {
      lb_ind = t.lastIndexOf("(", rb_ind);
  }
```

Comment: @user1022944 yes it will. I have corrected the compilation error.